# Does BIOS logs event such as power on/off?

Tags: linux, windows, security, bios

I would like to know if someone opened my notebook.
Note:  I can't use Windows Event Viewer because someone can just insert a Live CD Linux to boot the PC bypassing windows.

So does the BIOS save any logs when someone power on/off the PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. You can lock bios with password and lock booting from other drives.

There is no security when somebody has physical access to your computer though :)

Comment: I agree with you, but a simple logging on the BIOS could give a lot of information, that's sad that is impossible to get. Maybe if they have used a live CD, they have opened some files, can I track this information on my hard disk? (with windows)

Comment: You can check access time of the files on your drive, but one can mount the drive with noatime flag.